# Unable to edit code in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, editor

I've been using Visual Studio 2013 for several months now, and this morning I suddenly started running into a problem where I am unable to edit any of the code files.  When I try to type to add or change code, or try to delete code from a file, or try to copy and paste code into a file nothing happens at all.  All I am able to do (as far as I can tell) is move the cursor around in the file.  Does anyone know what may be causing an issue like this?

Comment: Restart VS. Does it fix the issue? If yes, it's a bug with an easy workaround, just deal with it. In my experience once bugs start showing up in VS, often the only sure way back to a reliable environment is a reinstall. But I'd try removing all of your add-ins first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This exact thing happened to me. Do you have ReSharper? If so, the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178283/cannot-edit-checked-out-file-tfs-in-visual-studio-2013) may work for you. From Alexander's comment in the accepted answer:

> Try cleaning R# caches C:\Users{User
>   Name}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\ and then
>   reopen the solution

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this with VS 2013.3 and in one branch of a TFS workspace. I could only enter code via intellisense, no paste or typing, although I could edit SpecFlow feature files. 
I created a new TFS workspace in the end and that solved it.