# Cannot edit checked out file (TFS) in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, resharper, edit, vcs-checkout

Since I changed my windows password I can no longer type into a checked out file in Visual Studio 2013! Where before I just needed to start typing and it would check out the file in the background, now it won't even allow me to type into the file after I manually check the file out, from the solution explorer! It's as if VS 2013 is ignoring the keyboard on the project under source control. It's fine for other projects even project's under source control!

I think I remember seeing this before with older versions of Visual Studio and resolved it with a "Go online" option  but I can't see that option in VS 2013, or the project is not "off line" so the option is not available.

This is obviously related to the TFS setting on the project but I simply cannot get past it. I am blocked and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: If you go to the Team Explorer, can you then open your Team Project and navigate to the Source Control Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I can do that without a problem. Source control explorer is available. I am trying to eliminate Resharper as a culprit, right now. I noticed that the icon on scroll bar that tells me if the code in the file is OK (green box with a tick in it) or has errors or warnings, is missing on the project with the problem but present on the project without this problem.

Comment: Is the project created in TFS 2013? Are you using local workspaces? If so, you won't have to checkout a file before editing it.

Comment: Wouter, thanks for your help. I was Resharper! I put it into suspend mode and restarted VS 2013 and the problem just went away. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I suspended Resharper and restarted Visual Studio 2013. Once I reopened it the problem was gone. Resuming Resharper caused the problem to emerge again.

The solution is quite large so maybe that is it. Before putting Resharper into suspend mode I tried switching off code analysis thinking the workload is just too great, but that didn't help. The suspend did though. I hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

All I have to do now is to figure out how to get Resharper back in the game without the problem coming back. We rely on Resharper as it is an wonderful tool. Since the solution has many projects in it, I am going to try create a smaller solution with my web project and  just reference the other projects as assemblies. Maybe that will help

Update:
Clearing the resharper cache as suggested by Alexander resolved the original issue.

Comment: Try cleaning R# caches C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\ and then reopen the solution

Comment: I never followed up with this, since I solved the problem by reducing the number of projects in my solution and referencing them instead. I went back to the original solution after clearing the resharper cache as you suggested and yes that worked. Thanks Alexander.

Comment: The problem I faced was I tried to get latest from TFS inside visual studio and then I cancelled it in half way. After that my VS crashed, I then restarted it again. The Edit didn't work after I restarted it, your solution helps me. Thankyou

Comment: You also can clear the cache in Visual Studio under `Resharper` --> `Options...` --> `Environment` --> `General` --> `Clear caches`. After that you also will have to reopen the solution.

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to add [Alexander's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802385/alexander) comment as answer, since it helped me exactly to solve the issue:

---

Clean R# (ReSharper) caches by deleting all folders (and files) from the path

`C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches\`

and then reopen the solution.

---

**Note:** (Thanks to [Antak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036728/antak) for providing this info!)

You can paste

`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches`

into file explorer's path textbox (open it via *<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>*, or use *<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>* and paste the path into the command window), this will resolve the physical path into your user's directory automatically.

Comment: That's `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\SolutionCaches` if opening via Win+R.

Comment: I didn't find my cach folder, I just pressed "Clean cach" in VS-Resharper menu and then reopen the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me.  All my JavaScript files went "dead."  By "dead" i mean that all the normal VS intellisense coloring/functionality was gone; js files were un-editable, although Resharper was still working sort of; all other non-js files seems to be normal.   In addition to Resharper, I had also previously installed Web Essentials and was using both tools.

First,  I cleared the R# caches as mentioned above by Alexander.  After restarting VS, this DID NOT work. JS files still dead.

Then i disabled Web Essentials.  Then I restarted.  THIS WORKED.

I then re-enabled Web Essentials, restarted again, and all seems to be OK.  Am crossing my fingers....

Comment: Disabling Web Essentials worked for me as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I too had this problem with the latest version of ReSharper (9.0.0.0), but clearing the cache as stated above did not work. I actually had to go into my ReSharper options (ReSharper -> Options -> General) and click the "Clear Caches" button. Once I did this and restarted VS everything is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Try: **`/safemode`**
I had a similar problem where I could not edit most of my files, but I could edit *.ps1 files.
I don't have TFS, I do have resharper and other plugins.
What worked for me was:

- Start visual studio in safe mode: `C:\..\IDE>devenv /safemode`
- Close VS.
- Start VS normally.

That probably has the same effect as suspending and resuming resharper, but I'm not sure which  plugin could be causing the problem. If you are having trouble this is something you could try.

Answer (score -1):

I hit the refresh(restart) and it solved a similiar problems so maybe you better try that before an IDE restar. `ctrl shift F5`